Inconsistent behavior of EXCEL formula functions TYPE and COUNTA depending on text length
While writing some custom lambdas in an Excel workbook I had inconsistent results (and even Excel crashes, with a recursive lambda) depending on the length of the input text.
I was able to trace down the issues to 2 Excel formula functions:
TYPE, which returns the type of the value as a numeric code.
COUNTA, which counts the number of values that are not empty.
The inconsistent behaviors arise with texts longer than 255 characters:

TYPE returns 64 (Array) instead of 2 (Text)
COUNTA, used with BYROW on an array containing such long texts, doesn't count them.

My version of Excel is up to date:
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2410 Build 16.0.18129.20158) 64 bits
Steps to reproduce
In order to reproduce the issues, here are 2 simple tables:
TYPE issue:

Column formulas are:
REPT    =REPT("x", [@[set LEN]])
ISTEXT  =ISTEXT([@REPT])
COUNTA  =COUNTA([@REPT])
LEN     =LEN([@REPT])
TYPE    =TYPE([@REPT])

note: the maximum length of a text in a cell is 32767, hence the error (TYPE 16) above it.
COUNTA issue:

Column formulas are:
REPT        =REPT("x", [@[set LEN]])
[ISTEXT]    =BYROW(VSTACK([@REPT]), ISTEXT)
[COUNTA]    =BYROW(VSTACK([@REPT]), COUNTA)
[COLUMNS]   =BYROW(VSTACK([@REPT]), COLUMNS)

VSTACKis used to transform the (1 cell) input into an array, but any other array function (like TOCOL) will achieve the same goal.
The issue doesn't show up when just using COUNTA(VSTACK([@REPT])), without BYROW.
But it still does when using an explicit LAMBDA in BYROW: BYROW(VSTACK([@REPT]), LAMBDA(v, COUNTA(v))).
Consequences and workaround
When using such functions on texts that can be longer than 255, one should not trust their output and test further the input using a combination of ROWS, COLUMNS, ISTEXT and LEN...
Questions
Does someone have a piece of explanation for these inconsistencies?
Are there other functions subject to similar issues?

It seems that classic XL strings can only be 0 to 255 characters long and after that they are really a special case of a signed array of char (TYPE=64). You would have to ask their engineers why they thought these design decisions were sensible. The COUNTA thing with LAMBDA functions would appear to be a bug in Office365.

It's not BYROW, it's COUNTA. Once you convert the range to an array the blanks are converted to empty strings: =COUNTA({"",1,""}) returns 3. (Also instead VSTACK you can use + in front of a range to convert it to an array).

The COUNTA function counts cells containing any type of information, including error values and empty text (""). For example https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509

@P.b thank you for the + trick! Indeed, it's not BYROW: the same arise with MAP... Yet, COUNTA is supposed to count any type of information, but fails when used on long strings in an ARRAY formula.

You're welcome. Glad it helped.
